# Using jQuery Remove() Method On Elements Rendered by Angular's Data Binding

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the following JS / jQuery code:

```
window.isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.isTouchDevice === false){
        $('.overlay').removeClass('touch-placeholder');
        $('.button-planes').remove();
        $('.button-cars').remove();
    }
});
```

The first line in the call-back function to remove 'touch-placeholder' class works.  The next two calls to the jQuery 'remove' method does not.  If I run either of those two lines in the browser console after the page loads, the elements are properly removed from the DOM.

The HTML I am running the JS on looks like the following:

```
<div class="myClass" ng-repeat="item in itemsContainer">
     <div class = 'touch-placeholder some-class'></div>
     <a href = '#' class = 'button-planes' ng-click = 'someFunction($index)'>
     <a href = '#' class = 'button-cars' ng-click = 'someFunction($index)'>
</div>
```

The HTML is bound to the Angular 'itemsContainer' array and renders DIVs based on the length of the array.  I put in alert breaks between the jQuery 'remove' methods and noticed that the HTML for the results hadn't been rendered yet even though I am using `$(document).ready`.

What is the best way of removing my anchor elements in this instance when the items I want to remove are rendered using Angular's data binding function?

Comment: Maybe you need the jquery but what about using ng:show instead? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a custom directive:

```
myModelApp.directive('onFinishRender', function($timeout){
        return function(scope, element, attrs){
            var isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
            //After last item is rendered, do the enclosed things
            if(scope.$last && isTouchDevice === true){
                $('.overlay').removeClass('touch-placeholder');
                $('.button-planes').remove();
                $('.button-cars').remove();
                //Other things you want to do  
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Add the directive into the HTML:

```
<!--Notice the camal-cased JavaScript name being transformed into one 
with dashes-->

<div class="myClass" ng-repeat="item in itemsContainer" on-finish-render>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you truly want to remove the DOM element you'll want to use [ngIf](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

I'd place a variable like isTouchEnabled on $rootScope then use ng-if="!isTouchEnabled" on the elements you want to remove